# Umbraco 7 GetDictionaryItem in WebAPI return empty string

Tags: asp.net-web-api, umbraco, umbraco7

I have umbraco 7.1.1 site. I have WebAPI method returns back a string. The string is constructed from a template. The issue I am having is that when in webapi i do GetDictionaryItem I get nothing back. The key and value definately exist becuase if I do GetDictionaryItem in template it works.

In my web.config I have added:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru-RU"/>
```

But DictionaryItem still return empty string. How make it works?

Regards, Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The umbraco dictionary items read the language that is set in the content section of the CMS. 
First you have to add the language you need (RU) in Settings, then apply the language on the node in the content section.

Setting the language on the page/node will tell Umbraco that umbraco should be rendering the template in Russian.